# value of the returned xml element in simple twisted SOAP server

Tags: python, soap, twisted, zsi

I am trying to change the value of the returned XML element of my simple twisted SOAP server. (I generated the server with `wsdl2py --twisted --complexType Myservice.wsdl`.)

My return element XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="ReplyMessage" type="ReplyTypeEnum">
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="ReplyTypeEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="OK" />
        <xs:enumeration value="NOT_VALID" />
        <xs:enumeration value="ERROR" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:simpleType>
```

My server currently returns this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:ReplyMessage/>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I would like to return this (i.e. the value `'OK'`):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:ReplyMessage>OK</ns1:ReplyMessage>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My Python code which should change the value looks like this:

```
def __composeResponse_OK(self, response):
    response._ReplyMessage = 'OK'
    return response
```

but that, obviously, doesn't work. I have tried a few other ways, but none of them works. I am simply unable to change the value of the returned response!

Is there a way to add the value `'OK'` (or `'ERROR'` or `'NOT_VALID'`) into my response?

Comment: I'm looking to develop a SOAP server with twisted. Can you give me some suggestions ?